# error in scrapy web crawler tutorial

Tags: python-2.7, web-crawler, scrapy

I am doing this simple scrapy crawler tutorial given on scrapy official website but getting some errors. I am doing this thing first time so completely unknown about all this. I need to implement web crawler in my application and i found scrapy to accomplish my needs so started with the tutorial and ended upon the error i have pasted below. Can any one please explain me whats wrong with the code..?

THIS IS MY CRAWLER CODE

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider

class DmozSpider(Spider):

    name="dmoz"

    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]

    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

   filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]

   open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)
```

THIS IS THE ERROR I AM GETTING

2014-02-04 10:45:51+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2014-02-04 10:45:51+0530 [dmoz] DEBUG: Crawled (200) http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/> (referer: None)

ERROR: Spider error processing http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1178, in mainLoop
        self.runUntilCurrent()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 800, in runUntilCurrent
        call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 362, in callback
        self._startRunCallbacks(result)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 458, in _startRunCallbacks
        self._runCallbacks()
    ---  ---
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 545, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spider.py", line 56, in parse
        raise NotImplementedError
    exceptions.NotImplementedError:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this error means you didn't implement `parse` function in your spider, on the other hand according to the posted code it seem that you did, leading me to think you are having an indentation issue causing the code to believe `parse` function is not a part of DmozSpider class